# How to get access to props of third-party child in third-party component using react

Tags: reactjs, reflection

I have my component with similar `render()` method:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Form/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `<Form>` is a third-party component, so I can't simply change it's implementation, and it has some children of it's own:

```
<Form>
  <div>
    <Child1/>
    <Child2/>
    <Child3/>
  </div>
</Form>
```

where all `<Child1>`, `<Child2>` and `<Child3>` are also some other third-party-components.

How can I get access to properties of `<Child2>` from my component and set some of these during run-time in React?

Comment: Can you provide the name of the third part lib ? Usually they let you pass them some functions as props like for `onChange`etc.

Comment: `<Form/>` is `<SchemaForm>` from [react-schema-form](https://github.com/networknt/react-schema-form); `<Child2/>` is `<TextField>` from [material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/)